# Highlighting edges in D3 by hovering mouse over nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and I'm using this template (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292) to visualize my graph. I'd like to highlight the links that are connected to a node by hovering mouse over the node. I tried the technique used in (http://jsfiddle.net/2pdxz/2/) by adding the following lines to the script.

```
nodes.on('mouseover', function(d) {
  link.style('stroke-width', function(l) {
    if (d === l.source || d === l.target)
      return 4;
    else
      return 2;
    });
});

// Set the stroke width back to normal when mouse leaves the node.
nodes.on('mouseout', function() {
  link.style('stroke-width', 2);
});
```

But it seems not working for me and nothing happens when I move mouse over the nodes.

Comment: That's the right code for the job, what happens when you console.log(l) and console.log(d)? I would guess you're overwriting a variable somewhere.

Comment: I receive this error on the console when I hover mouse over nodes:  "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". Here is the link to jsfiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/bswv1mqe/

Comment: Found the problem and fixed it! I had to use path instead of link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the fundamentals of the code are correct, the problem was that the `link` variable should have been named `path`.